# File upload error in zend with google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, zend-framework, file-upload

I am uploading file in zend with google app engine and got the error "File uploads are not allowed in your php config!".

I am using the code......

```
$userId = (int) $this->params('id');
$fName = time().".".$extension;
$options = [ 'gs_bucket_name' => 'googlesurveys001'];
$upload_url =   CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('/admin/user/add-picture', $options);

$request = $this->getRequest();
if ($request->isPost()) {
    $File = $this->params()->fromFiles('name');
    $gs_name = $File['tmp_name'];
   move_uploaded_file($gs_name, 'gs://googlesurveys001'.'/images/'.$userId.'/'.$fName);
}
```

Any help would be wellcome.

Thanks 
Manish kumar

Comment: you can't write to the filesystem *at all* in GAE, so no temp file is allowed.  You have to put it straight in the bucket.

Comment: I have change it accordingly but got same error.

Comment: Can you share code of the form?

Comment: In the form tag after setting action attribute to $upload_url.Its working fine.

$upload_url =   CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('/admin/user/add-picture', $options);

<form action="<?php echo $upload_url?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

Answer (score 0):

In the form tag after setting action attribute to $upload_url.Its working fine.

```
$upload_url =   CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('/admin/user/add-picture', $options);

<form action="<?php echo $upload_url?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```